# Issues creating an HTTPS server to serve binaries and other files

Tags: go, https, server, fileserver

**What I want to achieve:**
An HTTPS server designed specifically to serve binaries to around 1000 devices, sometimes in the same time (clients will fetch the binaries via wget, curl, browser download, etc).

**Key functionality features:**

- client won't be able to download the binary without a certificate
- server will allow the client directory browsing/download via browser(if client has certificate)
- server is optimized for stability and security, then for speed
- server must use high security ciphers and TLS1.2

**What I managed to achieve**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
        http.ServeFile(w, req, "/")
    })

    log.Printf("Server running\nAccess the server via: https://localhost:9900/")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":9900", "cert.crt", "priv.key", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/"))))
}
```

Now, this works fine although it doesn't check all the features and its not very flexible and somehow I wanted to make it more future proof, as I wish to both learn by creating this project and also expand on it in the future as I'm interested in learning more about servers.

After a bit of research I found several code pieces on GitHub and in tutorials, which led me to put together the following piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Add("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains")
        http.ServeFile(w, req, "/")

    })
    cfg := &tls.Config{
        MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
        CurvePreferences:         []tls.CurveID{tls.CurveP521, tls.CurveP384, tls.CurveP256},
        PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
        CipherSuites: []uint16{
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
            tls.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
        },
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":9900",
        Handler:      mux,
        TLSConfig:    cfg,
        TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(*http.Server, *tls.Conn, http.Handler), 0),
    }
    log.Printf("Server running\nAccess the server via: https://localhost:9900/")
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("cert.crt", "priv.key"), http.FileServer(http.Dir("/")))

}
```

Problem is that when the server starts and I connect to it via browser, I'm presented with the root directory but every time I click on a folder the URL increments the address but the page just refreshes in the "/" directory.

**To be exact:**

- I connect initially to the server and I'm presented the root directory , I'm shown Dir1, Dir2, Dir3
- I click Dir1
- The URL modifies from https://localhost:9900 to https://localhost:9900/Dir1
- But I'm still in the root directory

From what I'm able to see...I think I'm creating a loop somewhere.
If anyone knows what I need to do to make this functional, help would be much appreciated.

**NOTE**
The above behavior is on Firefox, on Chrome I get one of the 2 errors in the server error log, depending on changes that I make:

- 2019/09/29 19:59:37 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:53287: EOF
- 2019/09/29 19:15:59 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:50457: tls: client doesn't support selected certificate

Comment: You're always serving `/` (third argument to ServeFile), independent of the request path. Have you considered [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer)?

Comment: Hi @peter , I've added **http.FileServer(http.Dir("/"))** instead of **http.ServeFile(w, req, "/")** and now i get blank page as a response. Not grasping how http works yet or I'm missing something.

Comment: The documentation is clear and thorough, and includes multiple examples, I'd highly recommend taking a look at the docs for the libraries you're using. For example, here's `http.FileServer` and its three examples: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples elsewhere on how to do this (as has been commented).

Here's a worked example in which the fileserver handler is an enhanced version of that in the standard library that supports more cache headers and locally-compressed files. The standard fileserver handler can be dropped in here instead if that's what you need.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/rickb777/servefiles/v3"
)

var path = flag.String("path", "..", "directory for the files tp be served")
var cert = flag.String("cert", "", "file containing the certificate (optional)")
var key = flag.String("key", "", "file containing the private key (optional)")
var port = flag.Int("port", 8080, "TCP port to listen on")
var maxAge = flag.String("maxage", "", "Maximum age of assets sent in response headers - causes client caching")
var verbose = flag.Bool("v", false, "Enable verbose messages")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *verbose {
        servefiles.Debugf = log.Printf
    }

    if (*cert != "" && *key == "") ||
        (*cert == "" && *key != "") {
        log.Fatal("Both certificate file (-cert) and private key file (-key) are required.")
    }

    h := servefiles.NewAssetHandler(*path)

    if *maxAge != "" {
        d, err := time.ParseDuration(*maxAge)
        log.Printf("MaxAge: %s %v\n", d, err)
        h = h.WithMaxAge(d)
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port),
        Handler: h,
    }

    if *cert != "" {
        srv.TLSConfig = &tls.Config{
            MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
            CurvePreferences:         []tls.CurveID{tls.CurveP521, tls.CurveP384, tls.CurveP256},
            PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
            CipherSuites: []uint16{
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
                tls.TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
            },
        }
        log.Printf("Access the server via: https://localhost:%d/", *port)
        log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS(*cert, *key))

    } else {
        log.Printf("Access the server via: http://localhost:%d/", *port)
        log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
    }
}
```

Source code https://github.com/rickb777/servefiles/blob/master/v3/webserver/example.go